# Yocto: get debug info about variables(values)

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

I am new in yocto project and now I really need to do this simple task.

I have the part of .bb recipe file:

```
S = "${WORKDIR}"

HELLO = "hello"

HELLO = "hell"
SRC_URI = "file://myserver.tar.gz"

do_compile() {
        make
}
```

And now I want to track the values of my variable, for example, HELLO.
I am introduced with command bitbake -e, but it seems like it shows my only the last modification of this variable, but I need to see "hello" value and "hell" value in debug information

Thanks !

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, if for some reason it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `logging` [class](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/classes/logging.bbclass):

```
inherit logging

bb.debug("HELLO = %s" % HELLO)
```